# Angularjs nested routing using $stataProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am stuck on issue, in which , I clicked on second tab (chat) , it contains list of items and when i clicked on one of them it will show details of that item and upper left corner will show left arrow & title. then it will change tabs at bottom , I want to  make all tab common for items info and on every tab clicked it should have back arrow & title.
The arrow should have common back link , suppose i click on back button i show list of items.

```
I tried my 1 week please let me help to sort out this this , below  has mentioned the thing which i have done so far.

http://codepen.io/ssharma01/pen/xwdBye
```

Thanks
Shivam